# Can anyone properly explain me the characteristic curve of the p-type JFET?

Tags: power-electronics, semiconductors, jfet, solid-state-devices

I know how a MOSFET works. But recently I wanted to know details about JFET.
 [image][image]

When V(GS) = 0 volts there will obviously a current flowing through the p-type channel. What confuses me is how the drain current is reduced when a positive voltage is applied. The gate terminal is connected to the n-type material. So, a depletion region will be created. But it is not narrowing the p-channel path that existed at V(GS) = 0 volts. So, how the drain current is reduced?

Please, someone, explain to me how this is happening.

Comment: Why do you say it's not narrowing the channel? Sure looks like it is to me.

Comment: Is it like, the positive gate voltage attracting the electrons, so n-type is attracted towards the gate? At the same time positive gate voltage repulsing the positive charge and narrowing the channel. I thought this just right now.

Comment: **FIG 6.13** has some goofy DC polarity markings. \$V_{GG}\$ looks good, but \$V_{DD}\$ does not.

Comment: I've seen that. It's from the book of Robert L. Boilstade.